# Splitting a .ashx Generic Handler into Partial Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have been trying to split my generic handler into multiple files. It is designed to receive all commands and all request types from a page, so I have it processing GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE with multiple commands for each request. Thus, there is a lot of code. I was wondering if I could split this. I tried using partial classes but the methods in the handler can't see the methods in the partial class file.

Comment: Share your code. Its difficult to provide a good solution without seeing what exactly is not working.

Comment: Check you're using a compiled web application and not "websites". Also ensure that your `partial` classes are all in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy using WebAPI if that is possible for you so you don't have to separate your code like this. If you can do that, take a look at http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/03/05/introduction-to-the-asp-net-web-api.aspx to explain it better.

sorry if this is not what you are asking but thought I'd throw it out there in case you did not know about it.